# How to keep track of state across a mapped array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, essentially I wanted to keep track of the state value in a React component while making changes or adding to the original array. Sounds vague but let me explain it with an example

I have a component that's basically rendering a array for this data format

```
[
  {
    Name: '',
     Age: '',
     Gender: ''
  }
]
```

The component is similar to this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import jsonData from './json-data.js'

export default function Search() {

  const [name, setname] = useState('')
  const [age, setage] = useState('')
  const [gender, setgender] = useState('')

  const [data, setData] = useState({jsonData})

  const addsection = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let dataStr = {
      name: '',
      address: '',
      gender: ''
    }

    /** creates another section with empty data fields*/
    setData([...data, dataStr])
  }

  const save = () => {
   POST request goes here
  }
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={addsection}> Add another section </button>
    {data.map((item, index) => (
       <div key={index}>
          <input value={item.name} onChange={event => setname(event.target.value)}/> 
          <input value={item.age} onChange={event => setage(event.target.value)}/> 
          <input value={item.gender}  onChange={event => setgender(event.target.value)}/> 
       </div>
    ))}

    <button onClik={save}> Save</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Now the main problem is let's say I create two empty fields and work on both of them. Sometimes on the input of the first object and sometimes on the second object. How do I keep track of state here?

Comment: use `setData` and change values based on `index`.

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of state?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using duplicate states for same data like name, age & gender, update them directly in data state. There is no need for extra states apart from data.

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest way to go about is to create a parent Component, like Searches(), that has an add button. For example:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Search from 'path-to-Search-component';

export default function Searches() {

  const [searches, setSearches] = useState([]);
  const [searchesNum, setSearchesNum] = useState(0);

  const addsection = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let search = {
      id: searchesNum, /** using searchesNum as an id to be assigned to new Search compmonents **/
    }
    setSearchesNum(searchesNum + 1);

    /** adding new Search component to searches array **/
    setSearches([...searches, search]);
  }
  
  const deleteSection = (search_id) => {
    
    const index = searches.findIndex(
      (search) => search.id === search_id
    );
    let newSearches = [...searches];

    if (index >= 0) {
      newSearches.splice(index, 1);
      setSearches(newSearches);
    } else {
      console.warn(
        `Cant remove Search (id: ${search_id}) as its not in Searches!`
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={addsection}> Add another section </button>
    {searches.map((search) => (
      <Search key={search.id} id={search.id} deleteSection={deleteSection}></Search>
    ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

This is a parent component that holds multiple child components, Search in this case. I used two variables 'searches' (array of search object) and 'searchesNum' (id). Clicking the add button here will simply create a search object with a single property named 'id' (this is used as a key in the map function below). Another new thing I added is the deleteSection() function. This function is passed down as prop to all Search components. Here's how it will be used:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import jsonData from './json-data.js'

export default function Search({ id, deleteSection }) {

  const [name, setname] = useState('')
  const [age, setage] = useState('')
  const [gender, setgender] = useState('')
  
  const save = () => {
   /** POST request goes here **/
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input value={item.name} onChange={event => setname(event.target.value)}/> 
        <input value={item.age} onChange={event => setage(event.target.value)}/> 
        <input value={item.gender}  onChange={event => setgender(event.target.value)}/> 
      </div>
      
      <button onClick={() => deleteSection(id)}> Delete Section </button>
      <button onClik={save}> Save</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

On click, deleteSection() from the parent component is called, and the id of the Search component is used to identify which item needs to be removed from the searches array in the Searches component.

One more thing: I am not 100% sure, but buttons only refresh the page when placed inside the form tag, so there's no need for e.preventDefault() in your example.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi, there are not need to create a parent component. Just add the Id inside the object, and all the actions over the array will be using that id.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you mind explaining a bit more? I think there are many ways to go about it, but I think having a parent component or something similar to that to wrap multiple Search components inside is the best way to replicate state tracking, where each Search component is in charge of tracking their own name, age, and gender. This I believe improves the readability due to its simplicity.

Comment: Hi, you can resolve like you said in many ways, your solutions isnt wrong but in react the best solution is avoid to have extra states. With the data and the Id it will be enough just to keep track of the search values.